# Orphaned Inline Divs

Tags: html, css

I have a series of inline-block divs that can wrap onto a second line depending on how wide the browser is at a given time. Here's a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tbutler/vbs12gne/). For example, it might look like this:

[image]

However if the viewport is of a certain width, it can end up with just one orphaned inline-block on the next line:

[image]

Is there a CSS method that is essentially some form of "orphan control" (CSS `orphan` doesn't seem to apply in this situation) so that if there are fewer than a certain number of elements on the second line, it'd wrap more of them down there to even things out?

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 6
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 7
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you move onto a second row do you want each item still to be fixed at 50px width or to expand so the space is more covered (which is what your first image looks like).

Comment: @A Haworth I want to keep it the same size on the second -- to get it to wrap I had to resize the browser window which made a wider image that StackOverflow has scrunched up a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using CSS grid where the trick is to make sure your div has a width expressed as a multiple of a fixed amount to make sure you never have an orphan element.

```css
.wrapper {
  --w: 100px; /* width of one item */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, calc(2*var(--w))); /* the item will break two by two*/
  justify-content:center;
}

.container {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
.item {
  width: calc(var(--w) - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}


/* irrelevant styles */

.container {
  counter-reset: num;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.item::before {
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(class) " " counter(num);
  counter-increment: num;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we use `3`

```css
.wrapper {
  --w: 100px; /* width of one item */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, calc(3*var(--w))); 
  justify-content:center;
}

.container {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
.item {
  width: calc(var(--w) - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}


/* irrelevant styles */

.container {
  counter-reset: num;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.item::before {
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(class) " " counter(num);
  counter-increment: num;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex and flex-wrap for this with break points so you can decide how many items are in the top row on each width. Where it is inevitable that there is a single item on the last row this snippet goes for minimising the number of rows.

It would have been nice to use CSS variables for all of this so the choice is easily altered, but you can't use variables in media queries so we have to put them in by hand.

```css
.container {
    width: 104px; /* item width plus 2 lots of padding */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 312px) {
  .container {
    width: 312px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 416px) {
  .container {
    width: 416px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 728px) {
  .container {
    width: 728px;
  }
}


.item {
    r-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 0 0 100px; /* made 100px so easier to test on different widthe */
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 6
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 7
    </div>
</div>
```